# Load data by one button, plot data by a second button

Tags: excel, matlab, user-interface, plot

I have a GUI in Matlab, and several buttons, by one button I need to load a file (I don't want the directory to be shown) and by second button plot determined data.

Code for the first button:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.xlsx;*.xls'});
```

Code for the second button:

```
fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r'); 


handles.fileData = xlsread(strcat(pathname, filename));


axes(handles.axes1);
plot(handles.fileData(:,1),'-k')
hold on;
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(handles.fileData(:,2),'k')
```

I get an error message all the time:

Undefined function or variable 'pathname'.

HOw can I pass the function to the second button?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: print `pathname`, what does it say?

Comment: Define the pathname as global at the beginning of each function

Answer (score 0):

Ad hoc solution is using: [setappdata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [getappdata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html).

Example:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
setappdata(0, 'pathname', 'abc');

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname'); % Return 'abc'.
```

---

Another simple solution is passing `pathname` in `UserData` member of the parent figure.
When both buttons are in the same figure, `hObject.Parent` is the `handle` to the figure, and `UserData` element is a "preparation" for passing data between GUI objects.

Example:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
hObject.Parent.UserData.pathname = 'abs';

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
pathname = hObject.Parent.UserData.pathname; %Value is 'abc'
```

---

For more information refer to: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html

---

Complete code sample without using `guide` tool:
I created the following sample without using `guide` tool because there is no simple way passing the `fig` file of `guide` in Stack Overflow.

```
function TestNoGuide()
    clear all
    close all

    % Create figure
    hObject = figure('position', [800 400 260 100], 'Toolbar','none');
    % create structure of handles
    handles = guihandles(hObject);
    handles.hObject = hObject;

    handles.pushbutton1 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[10 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button1');
    handles.pushbutton2 = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'position',[150 20 100 40], 'string' , 'Button2');
    set(handles.pushbutton1, 'callback', {@pushbutton1_Callback, handles});
    set(handles.pushbutton2, 'callback', {@pushbutton2_Callback, handles});

    %Save the structure
    guidata(hObject);
end


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)    
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.xlsx;*.xls'});
    setappdata(0, 'filename', filename);
    setappdata(0, 'pathname', pathname);
end

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)   
    filename = getappdata(0, 'filename');
    pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname');
    waitfor(warndlg(['filename = ', filename, '   pathname = ', pathname]));
end
```

Check it out, and tell me if it's working on your machine...

Comment: Didn't work out.

This is what I get after I write pathname and filename in the Command Window seperatly:

    Undefined function or variable 'pathname'.
    Undefined function or variable 'filename.

Comment: Try writing `pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname')` in the Command Window.

Comment: The variable  is not `global`, so it is not visible in Command Window (scope rules defines where variables are visible). You can use `assignin('base','pathname',pathname)` to pass `pathname` value to workspace. Did you try placing a breakpoint inside the callback of the pushbutton, and then writing `pathname` in Command Window?

Comment: Undefined function or variable "pathname".

    Error in GUI_BP>pushbutton2_Callback (line 106)
    fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r');

    Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
            feval(varargin{:});

     Error in GUI_BP (line 42)
      gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

     Error in    @(hObject,eventdata)GUI_BP('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdat a,guidata(hObject))

 
    Error while evaluating UIControl Callback










 
I have got this error above.
Is it a sophisticated errow, or it's easy to solve it out?

Comment: Looks simple: all it says is `pathname` in not a valid variable. This is because `pathname` is "out of scope". Insert the code line: `pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname')` one code line before `fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r');`

Comment: Insert the code line: `setappdata(0, 'pathname', pathname);` one code line after `[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.xlsx;*.xls'});`

Comment: Make sure file name is selected before executing `fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r');`. Make sure you have no `clear` command (like `clear all`) in your code.

Comment: Should I also put pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname') somewhere, or only fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r');  ? Because the line fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r'); 

I have put there already before, and didn't work out.

Comment: Insert the code line: `pathname = getappdata(0, 'pathname')` one code line before `fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r');`

Comment: I will try it out, and let you know.

Comment: You may also try out the code I added to my post (after my last edit).